# rails SimpleForm, radio buttons among other text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

If i create a radio button in this way:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :my_field, [['key 1', 'Description 1'], 
                                           ['key 2', 'Description 2']], 
:first, :last %>
```

I get the classic look (well, actually i've added a display: block; css too,to get this):
Choose an option:
* Description 1
* Description 2

But i can't do this because the look that i want to achieve is one in which the options are sorrounded by other text, like this:
If you choose the * Description 1, you will get something, while if you 
choose the * Description 2, you will get some other thing. You also might * renonuce, in that case you'll have nothing.

I need to break the component into the single option buttons, but how?

Comment: DO I understant right that you want buttons to be inline inside text?

Comment: yes, and not in precise positions but potentially everywhere in the form